# How to find the pH at the equivalence point using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, graph, chemistry

> Create a function that finds the largest derivative in the derivative
> list. Feel free to compare with the numpy function max. Let the
> program print out what volume this corresponds to. This is the volume
> of strong base added at the equivalence point. Also find the pH at the
> equivalence point using your program.

I was able to find the first part of the question by making a function to find max and got the correct answer from that, but im stuck on how to use that information to find the pH at the equivalence point.

My code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fil = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/andreasdh/programmering-i-kjemi/master/docs/datafiler/titreringsdata.txt', delimiter = ",")

volum = fil['volum']
pH = fil['pH']

print(pH, volume)

plt.plot(volum, pH, color = "#B00B69", label = "Tilpasset modell")
plt.scatter(volum, pH, color = "hotpink", label = "Datapunkter")
plt.xlabel("volum")
plt.ylabel("pH")
plt.grid()
plt.show()

d = []
for i in range(len(volum)-1):
    dery = pH[i+1] - pH[i]
    dert = volum[i+1] - volum[i]
    dydt = dery/dert
    d.append(dydt)

print(d)

def fmax(list):
    max = list[0]
    for x in list:
        if x > max:
            max = x
    return max
print('the biggest element in the derivative is', fmax(d))
```

I believe that at somepoint I will ahve to use `matplotlib.pyplot` to make a graph and scatter the data around but still can't understand what I'm supposed to do.

Comment: How do you find the equivalence point without Python?

Comment: [OH] = kb * [base] / [acid] and then pOH = -log [OH] and lastly pH = 14 - pOH.
Am I just supposed to make a code for pOH and pH calculations?

Comment: Apparently yes, if you want to calculate the pH.

Comment: @MelissaRodrigues were you able to write the functions and solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

at the line 7 and 8, i used np.array() to get data.

this is my code:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import minimize

excel_file = "Untitled.xlsx"
#df = pd.read_excel(excel_file, sheet_name='Sheet1', usecols='A:B', skiprows=1)

#print(df)
# Sample data 
x = np.array(pd.read_excel(excel_file, sheet_name='Sheet1', usecols='A', skiprows=1)) #Vol
y = np.array(pd.read_excel(excel_file, sheet_name='Sheet1', usecols='B', skiprows=1)) #pH
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()

#first derivative
y1 = []
x1 = []
for i in range(len(x)):
    if(i != 0) :
        dery = y[i] - y[i-1]
        dert = x[i] - x[i-1]
        dydt = dery/dert
        x1.append((x[i] + x[i-1]) / 2)
    else :
        dydt = y[1] - y[0] / x[1] - x[0]
        x1.append((x[1] + x[0]) / 2)
    y1.append(dydt)
plt.plot(x1, y1)
plt.show()

def fmax(list):
    max = list[0]
    for i in range(len(y1)):
        if(list[i] > max):
            maxIndex = i
    return x[maxIndex - 1]
print('o ponto de inflexao se encontra no volume: ', fmax(y1))

#to calcul acid concentration
molMassAcid = 60.052
densityAcid = 1.05
volOfAcid = 3 + 40
cOfAcid = (0.1 * fmax(y1)) / volOfAcid #cAcid * volAcid = cNaOH * vNaOH
c = (cOfAcid * molMassAcid) * volOfAcid / 3 #cocentration in mass / L
print(c, "g por litro. a amostra apresenta ", c/10, "%")

#second derivative
y2 = []
x2 = []
for i in range(len(x1)):
    if(i != 0) :
        dery = y1[i] - y1[i-1]
        dert = x1[i] - x1[i-1]
        dydt = dery/dert
        x2.append((x1[i] + x1[i-1]) / 2)
    else :
        dydt = y1[1] - y1[0] / x1[1] - x1[0]
        x2.append((x1[1] + x1[0]) / 2)
    y2.append(dydt)
plt.plot(x2, y2)
plt.show()
```

manually, i filled some variables to get acid concentration according to my experiment in the lab. you can get the inflection point from the max point in a range of the first derivative.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).